# to keep power as constant either voltage or current changes

Tags: power, transistors, batteries, transformer, power-electronics

ohm's law states that voltage and current are proportional to each other. but my doubt is that "to keep power as constant either voltage or current changes" here the voltage and current are inversely proportional to each other.when does the power satisfies the ohm's law?

Comment: Explain why Power (voltage * current) would **need** to satisfy Ohm's law. Also you forgot about the **Resistor** which is what Ohm's law is all about, that's why we honor Mr Ohm by mentioning the value of resistors in **Ohms**.

Comment: What are you quoting? And what exactly is your question?

Comment: when voltage increases current also will increase.  for constant power voltage and current changes inversely. why it is happening?

Comment: "when voltage increases current also will increase" - Your initial thinking is already fundamentally flawed by not considering what part the resistor plays as FakeMoustache mentions

Comment: I have to admit, the OP has a point. The statement *"to keep power as constant either voltage or current changes*" is flawed. It should read "*To keep power constant, if voltage increases current must decrease and vica-versa.*" No idea where he is reading that from, since he quotes no source, but wherever it is, it is incorrect. Either that or he is quoting it out of context.

Answer (score 1):

Ohm's Law applies to resistors. Here voltage is proportional to current, if the resistance stays constant.

Power stays constant across an ideal transformer, or a DC to DC converter, which is a totally different beast, and has different laws. Here, power out is equal to power in (less losses), and a change of output voltage is met with an inverse change in output current to keep the power constant.

Trying to interpret the behaviour of one component with a law meant for another is dooooomed to failure.

Comment: mr.neil thamk you for your valuable answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to Ohm's law, since it's defined for resistors, if voltage increases then current will increase as well.

But if you're asking how can the current decrease if the voltage increases so that the power remains constant then the only example I can give is not a resistive system: Switchmode converter.

The following symbolizes a converter with transformer *(Of course it can be without a transformer as well)*.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWrA0q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Simply, to keep the power across the load constant, control circuitry maintains (via feedback) the input current if the input voltage varies.

Comment: They look like they're smooching eachother :)